# decoding xml characters in rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, coffeescript

I am trying to render coffee script in a textarea. The coffee script is fetched from a file which has been saved with utf-8 encoding. I have tried using the gem htmlentities on the coffee script to no avail. The gem seems to work on other strings in that view, its just this output thats the problem.

The file content:

```
jason = ->
   alert "jason"
   return
```

The output of that file:

```
jason = -&gt;\n  alert \&quot;jason\&quot;\n  return\n
```

My controller method

```
def create
item_to_delete = JsCoffee.last
item_to_delete.destroy if item_to_delete
@js_coffee = JsCoffee.new(js_coffee_params)
@result = @js_coffee.save
@code = @js_coffee.code
@success = 'Conversion complete'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
@output = coder.decode(@js_coffee.output)
respond_to do |f| 
  f .html{ redirect_to js_coffee_path(@js_coffee)}
    f.js 
      end
end
```

The model in which I save the file

```
before_create :empty_output

def empty_output
  if File.zero?('public/temp/js/output/output_temp_file.coffee')
    errors.add(:code, 'There was an error with the conversion, please check your code')
  else
    self.output = File.read('public/temp/js/output/output_temp_file.coffee', encoding: 'UTF-8')
    true
  end   
end
```

And the js.erb view file where I show the output of the file

```
<% if @result %>

  $('.alert').remove();
  editor2 = ace.edit('editor2')
  editor2.setTheme('ace/theme/textmate');
  editor2.getSession().setTabSize(2)
  editor2.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(true)
  editor2.setShowPrintMargin(false)
  editor2.setHighlightActiveLine(false)
  editor2.session.setFoldStyle('manual')
  editor2.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/coffee')
  editor2.setValue("<%= j @output %>");

  $('#new_js_coffee').prepend("<div class='alert alert-success'><%= j @success %>\
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>\
  </div>");


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not in htmlentities but to print out the raw html as in:

```
editor2.setValue("<%= j raw @output %>");
```